# How does UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic determine which animation to use?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

The iOS 5 SDK introduced a new animation type for table cell insertions and deletions: `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic`. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewrowanimation/uitableviewrowanimationautomatic) for this value simply states:

> The table view chooses an appropriate animation style for you.

So, err, how does this work, exactly? What factors does the table view take into account? The length of the table? The visible data? The phase of the moon?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on where the row is being inserted.

Normally, if you're manipulating rows at the start or end of a section and choose an inappropriate animation, the row might be displayed *behind* the section header/footer as it animates. The purpose of `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` is to let the table view automatically select an animation that looks good.

For example, when a row is being inserted at the *beginning* of a section, the table view will use `UITableViewRowAnimationBottom`. When it's is being inserted at the *end* of a section, the table view will use `UITableViewRowAnimationTop`.

The WWDC 2011 session ["UITableView Changes, Tips, Tricks"](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#uitableview-changes-tips-tricks) goes into more detail at around 
 3:25.